# What is the relationship between the product of function integrals and the integral of function products?

Tags: calculus, integration, inequality

When I'm doing some scaling of integrals, I always meet the question about how can I do with 【the product of function integrals and the integral of function products】

I know Cauchy but it's in the square case, so I'm puzzled whether there are any inequalities  between

$\begin{aligned} & \int f(x) g(x) d x& and  && \int f(x) d x·\int g(x) d x\end{aligned}$

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a partial answer to your question:

- There is no constant $C>0$ such that $\int f g \leq C \int f \cdot \int g$ for all $f,g \in L(\mathbb{R})$.
- There is no constant $C>0$ such that $\int f \cdot \int g \leq C \int f g$ for all $f,g \in L(\mathbb{R})$.

For the first point consider $f = g = n \cdot \mathbb{1}_{[0,1/n]}$ where $\mathbb{1}_{[0,1/n]}$ is the indicator function of the interval $[0,1/n]$. Then $\int fg \to \infty$  for $n\to \infty$ but $\int f \cdot \int g = 1$ for every $n$.
For the second point choose $f = n \cdot \mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}$ and e.g. $g = \mathbb{1}_{[2,3]}$. Then $\int f \cdot \int g = n \to \infty$ for $n \to \infty$ but $\int f g = 0$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$.